# Wordpress - Apply remove_filter only on one page

Tags: wordpress

I am inserting multiple pages in one page (with showmultiplepages plugin), and one page includes a php file (with exec-php).
I want to disable a filter only for this included page. If I add

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

to my included page, any page comming after this page won't have filters too.

Is there some tag like 'the_page' so that only the page will have no filter?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest creating a page template for the "one page includes a php file (with exec-php)". Then add an if statement around the remove_filter(...) statement.

```
if (!is_page_template('my-page.php'))
  remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

Hope it works. ;P

Comment: My pleasure. You may want to change the is_page_template() to other conditional tag. I'm wondering whether my idea works or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I'd chime in for anyone looking to do this in a more general sense (e.g. not in conjunction with plugin output) and say that you could also just add this to your `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'specific_no_wpautop', 9);
function specific_no_wpautop($content) {
    if (is_page('YOUR PAGE')) { // or whatever other condition you like
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
        return $content;
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `global $post;`

Comment: mmm, your're right @henrywright- use of the_content() template tag requires that it be used within the loop, so, indeed, the $post variable is already available.

Answer edited.

Comment: This works. In order to use this on, let's say, "About" page of your website, you would write the check as `if (is_page('about'))`. Append the condition with the `||` operator to include more pages.

Comment: @Devner `is_page()` now supports an array, so you can roll it all in one: `if( is_page( array( 'about', 'contact', 'management' ) )`

Comment: @rnevius That's super cool & even better. Thanks for sharing. I look forward to using it in my next project. +1 just for this update :)

Answer (score 2):

Like mroncetwice, I too realize that this is an old question; however, I came to this thread looking for an answer when I saw his. I decided to improve upon it (in terms of suiting my own situation) and am sharing the results with the hope that it may also help others.

---

Turn wpautop on or off by default and list any exceptions:

```
/**
 * Allow or remove wpautop based on criteria
 */
function conditional_wpautop($content) {
    // true  = wpautop is  ON  unless any exceptions are met
    // false = wpautop is  OFF unless any exceptions are met
    $wpautop_on_by_default = true;

    // List exceptions here (each exception should either return true or false)
    $exceptions = array(
        is_page_template('page-example-template.php'),
        is_page('example-page'),
    );

    // Checks to see if any exceptions are met // Returns true or false
    $exception_is_met = in_array(true, $exceptions);

    // Returns the content
    if ($wpautop_on_by_default==$exception_is_met) {
        remove_filter('the_content','wpautop');
        return $content;
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter('the_content', 'conditional_wpautop', 9);
```

Answer (score -3):

Does not work?

```
add_filter('the_content', 'specific_no_wpautop', 9);
function specific_no_wpautop($content) {
    global $post;
    if (is_single('5136') || ('3820')){ // or whatever other condition you like
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
        return $content;
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm ... answer or question or simply duplicating another answer?

Comment: This is the question of why the option is not applied to multiple pages? if (is_sangle('5136') || ('3820'))

Comment: well, if you have a question, please post a ... [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (this here is the _answer_ section :-)

Comment: Sorry, I have no time to write the same way. Problem was solved by adding to each page, a new function. Thank you.