# Show message after checking a checkbox - HTML Contact form

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I tried following the steps of this [link](https://css-tricks.com/exposing-form-fields-radio-button-css/) but I can't make it work.

I am trying to make it so that in a contact form, made in WordPress through HTML, if the user checks a box something else will show up. I implemented the code that appears in the link in my webpage and added the CSS (not SCSS) to the custom CSS page detail that Wordpress allows you to do. But even though I think I followed all the right steps the message that should appear only if the box is checked is always shown.

The example that was given I shortened it to

```
<form name="Inscripción" method="POST" onsubmit="return" form_validation()="" action="../customer-details.php">. 
<input type="radio" name="choice-animals" id="choice-animals-dogs"><br>
<label for="choice-animals-dogs">I like dogs more</label><p></p>. 
<div class="reveal-if-active"> Anything you want in here. </div>
</form>
```

And the CSS added was

```
.reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .reveal-if-active,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 100px; /* little bit of a magic number :( */
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Thank you for any help you might provide!

Comment: Your code is working fine, I've checked here https://jsfiddle.net/6z3ksqmw/
Perhaps there are some other CSS styles that are hiding the text

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The message is always shown, and WordPress keeps adding `<p></p>` in random places.

Comment: Wordpress uses `<p>` tags to add new lines, you can turn it off removing the `wpautop` filter. 
Even with the `<p>` tags, with the form that you provided the code works fine ( check it out https://jsfiddle.net/swvkxzq5/).

Comment: Very nice webpage! It still doesn't work on my site though. I am using WordPress with Highend. I am trying to figure out why it doesn't work but I can't yet.

Comment: Hey, something not related to this,  this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285812/wordpress-apply-remove-filter-only-on-one-page) shows how to disable `wpautop` at certain webpages. After changing that setting, should it be immediate? I changed it, and there are still `<p></p>` added everywhere in the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code it seems working for me. if CSS code not working for you. you can use below jquery code to display the message on radio checked.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.reveal-if-active').hide();
        jQuery('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
                jQuery('.reveal-if-active').show();
            }
        });

    });
</script>
</head>

<form name="Inscripción" method="POST" onsubmit="return" form_validation="" action="../customer-details.php">. 
<input type="radio" name="choice-animals" id="choice-animals-dogs"><br>
<label for="choice-animals-dogs">I like dogs more</label><p></p>. 
<div class="reveal-if-active"> Anything you want in here. </div>
</form>
```